# Is it mandatory to run Database Designer for every schema in HP Vertica?

Tags: database-schema, vertica

Constantly i have been hitting with Resource pool allocation error after creating several tables in new schema.

After running the Database Designer in vertica for particular schema with all tables the queries are running fine.

Kindly help me to understand the concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Database Designer is optional; you don't have to use it at all.  Using it helps you optimize your physical layout, and if you're having trouble with resource-pool allocation it sounds like you might benefit from that.

From [the documentation](http://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/GettingStartedGuide/UsingDatabaseDeisgner/UsingDatabaseDesignerto.htm):

> The HP Vertica Database Designer:
>
> - Analyzes your logical schema, sample data, and, optionally, your sample queries.
> - Creates a physical schema design (a set of projections) that can be deployed automatically or manually.
> - Can be used by anyone without specialized database knowledge.
> - Can be run and rerun any time for additional optimization without stopping the database.
> - Uses strategies to provide optimal query performance and data compression.

You can run DBD for just a particular query (optimizes whatever's needed to support that query) or for your entire database.  It uses sample queries that you provide, so if your usage patterns change over time it can help to rerun it.